# Is it possible to infer return type of functions in mapped types in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I wanna map object of functions to another object of functions with functions type inference. Arguments of function inferred but functions result is `any`

```
type TOriginalFunction<TArg,TResponse> = (prefix: string, arg: TArg) => TResponse;

type TModifiedFunction<TArg,TResponse> = (arg: TArg) => TResponse;

function modify<TArg, TResponse>(
  func: TOriginalFunction<TArg, TResponse>
): TModifiedFunction<TArg, TResponse> {
  return (arg:TArg) => func("", arg);
}

type TSourceObject<T> = 
  {[K in keyof T]: TOriginalFunction<T[K], any>};

type TModifiedObject<T> =
  {[K in keyof T]: TModifiedFunction<T[K], any>};

function modifyAll<T>(obj: TSourceObject<T>): TModifiedObject<T> {
    const result: Partial<TModifiedObject<T>> = {};
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj) as (keyof T)[]) {
        const fetchifiedFunc = modify(obj[key]);
        result[key] = fetchifiedFunc;
    }
    return result as TModifiedObject<T>;
}

var f1:TOriginalFunction<string,string> = () => "";
var f2:TOriginalFunction<void,boolean> = () => false;

const ff=modifyAll({f1,f2});
const f1res=ff.f1(''); // wanna typeof f1res to be string
const f2res=ff.f2(); // wanna typeof f2res to be boolean
```

Tried

```
type TOriginalFunction<TArg,TResponse> = (prefix: string, arg: TArg) => TResponse;

type TModifiedFunction<TArg,TResponse> = (arg: TArg) => TResponse;

function modify<TArg, TResponse>(
  func: TOriginalFunction<TArg, TResponse>
): TModifiedFunction<TArg, TResponse> {
  return (arg:TArg) => func("", arg);
}

type TSourceObject<T extends {[key: string]:{arg:any,result:any}}> = 
  {[K in keyof T]: TOriginalFunction<T[K]['arg'], T[K]['result']>};

type TModifiedObject<T extends {[key: string]:{arg:any,result:any}}> =
  {[K in keyof T]: TModifiedFunction<T[K]['arg'], T[K]['result']>};

function modifyAll<T extends {[key: string]:{arg:any,result:any}}>(obj: TSourceObject<T>): TModifiedObject<T> {
    const result: Partial<TModifiedObject<T>> = {};
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj) as (keyof T)[]) {
        const fetchifiedFunc = modify(obj[key]);
        result[key] = fetchifiedFunc;
    }
    return result as TModifiedObject<T>;
}

var f1:TOriginalFunction<string, string> = () => "";
var f2:TOriginalFunction<void, boolean> = () => false;

const ff=modifyAll({f1,f2});
const f1res=ff.f1(''); // wanna typeof f1res to be string
const f2res=ff.f2(); // wanna typeof f2res to be boolean
```

But now everything `any`. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the return types that you want by using the generic `T` on `modifyAll` to describe the original object, and mapping from the original object to the modified version.

```
function modifyAll<T extends {[key: string]: TOriginalFunction<any, any>}>(obj: T): TModifiedObject<T> {....
```

```
type TModifiedObject<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends TOriginalFunction<infer Arg, infer Res> ? TModifiedFunction<Arg, Res> : never;
};
```

This gives clear typings to all of the return values, but it introduces a new error in the function implementation.  The object values of `T` all `extend` `TOriginalFunction<any, any>`, but the function body is not aware of the specific type.  So I had to assert correctness with

```
result[key] = fetchifiedFunc as TModifiedObject<T>[keyof T];
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Bmx2bw)