# Can typescript maintain return type when reducing multiple classes or objects of functions in a reducer method?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, type-inference

I found my problem difficult to express in the title but here it goes.

I have multiple objects that essentially follow this structure:

```js
type TUtilityFunction = {[key: string]: <T>(a: T, b: any) => T}
```

So for example:

```js
class UtilityA{
  DoSomeWork = function (arg1: SomeCustomType, arg2: string){
    // do some work
    return arg1;
  }

class UtilityB{
  DoSomeOtherWork = function (arg1: SomeCustomType, arg2: number){
    // do some work
    return arg1;
  }
}
```

What I want is to combine the 2 classes into one and maintain intellisense with the new reduced object.

So the new object would be a combination of the previous 2:

```js
{
  DoSomeWork: (arg1: SomeCustomType, arg2: string) => SomeCustomType,
  DoSomeOtherWork: (arg1: SomeOtherCustomType, arg2: number) => SomeCustomType
}
```

I've tried adapting this to my solution [Is it possible to infer return type of functions in mapped types in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972790/is-it-possible-to-infer-return-type-of-functions-in-mapped-types-in-typescript)

but that is only one object of functions, where is I can have multiple.

My best attempt is something like this:

```js
export const combineUtitilies = function <
    TUtilities extends {
        [TKey in keyof TUtilities ]: Record<keyof TUtilities [keyof TUtilities ], TUtilityFunction>;
    }
>(reducers: TUtilities ): Record<keyof TUtilities [keyof TUtilities ], TUtilityFunction> {
    return (Object.keys(reducers) as Array<keyof TUtilities >).reduce(
        <K extends keyof TUtilities >(
            nextReducer: {[key in keyof TUtilities [keyof TUtilities ]]: TUtilityFunction},
            reducerKey: K
        ) => {
            return {...nextReducer, ...reducers[reducerKey]};
        },
        {} as Record<keyof TUtilities [keyof TUtilities ], TUtilityFunction>
    );
};
```

Typescript allows me to do this but if I try to then use the method:

```js
const result = combineUtitilies({prop1: new UtilityA(), prop2: new UtilityB()});
```

then the type it results in is

```js
const result: Record<never, TUtilityFunction>
```

which makes sense I guess but Im stuck with trying to figure out how to infer the end result or somehow infer each utility class coming into the combine method.  It could have a varying number of utility classes as arguments but always at least 2.  Maybe this is not possible to do? Or if it is I'd gladly take some advice!

## Update

So the example I used is slightly contrived as I wanted to simplify the root of the problem.  And as [motto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21146235/motto) mentioned it did indeed work when just spreading the two classes into a new object.  However I noticed when working with my actual code that I was still getting never.

I believe it is because I had a private variable that was called the same thing in both classes.  Now that I've got that worked out , I need to figure out how to approach this problem.  The private variable is passed via the constructor and acts as a config variable so to expand on what I wrote earlier imagine the 2 classes looking like this:

```js
class UtilityA{

  private readonly config: TSomeConfigType;

  constructor(config: TSomeConfigType) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  DoSomeWork = function (arg1: SomeCustomType, arg2: string){
    // do some work
    return arg1;
  }

class UtilityB{

  private readonly config: TSomeConfigType;

  constructor(config: TSomeConfigType) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  DoSomeOtherWork = function (arg1: SomeCustomType, arg2: number){
    // do some work
    return arg1;
  }
}
```

Now running

```js
const result = {...new UtilityA({}), ...new UtilityB({})}
```

results in

```js
const result: {}
```

Which I guess makes sense again because its trying to combine 2 properties of a config instance with the same property as again [motto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21146235/motto) mentioned.  And in some cases this config property might be a different type.  So now I'm stuck wondering what a viable approach is to combine the utilities and maintain each instance of config.  I wonder if somehow the combine function needs to dynamically rename each config instance to a unique name.  But maybe again that sounds overkill.

What's a good strategy for this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue still... https://tsplay.dev/mAJLZW

Comment: Your right.  That's so strange Im not sure what I did differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that you're overcomplicating things a little.

What you're essentially doing here is taking the intersection of the arguments to `combineUtilities(...)` (give or take any instances where different utility class instances have members with overlapping names).

This requires very little code:

```js
const result = { ...(new UtilityA()), ...(new UtilityB()) }

/* Intellisense correctly derives the type:
const result: {
    DoSomeOtherWork: (arg1: SomeCustomType, arg2: number) => SomeCustomType;
    DoSomeWork: (arg1: SomeCustomType, arg2: string) => SomeCustomType;
}
*/
```

The bad news – since each class can name its member(s) however it likes, I don't think you're going to have quite the type safety you're hoping for. When you do the object spreading in that `.reduce(..)` call, you'll get everything defined in the class, even if it's not mentioned in some type contract. If you put some restriction on the method names that you want exposed in your combined reducer then you could restrict their types appropriately.

#### Update to address Update

Honestly it's a kinda weird situation, you're essentially trying to force a has-a relationship into an is-a relationship.

Once again, you can go a long way by simplifying. Since you're using classes for encapsulation then it may be best to embrace that. Pre-instantiate your utility classes, make sure you're binding `this` as required, and explicitly expose the appropriate methods:

```js
const utilA = new UtilityA(config);
const utilB = new UtilityB(config);

const result = {
    DoSomeWork: utilA.DoSomeWork.bind(utilA), // or bind in the constructor ...
    DoSomeOtherWork: utilB.DoSomeOtherWork.bind(utilB)
}
/* IntelliSense correctly derives the type:
const result: {
    DoSomeWork: (arg1: SomeCustomType, arg2: string) => SomeCustomType;
    DoSomeOtherWork: (arg1: SomeCustomType, arg2: number) => SomeCustomType;
}
*/
```

Comment: Updated my question with this is mind. Many thanks. If you have advice for how to approach the problem I would be very thankful.

Comment: @NordicFinKoder Updated the answer to address your update, hope it's helpful.

Comment: yes it was helpful thank you.  I ended up doing something a bit different, but more or less how you showed.  Thanks again.